# pylint not running on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

It seems that pylint on MacOS is not doing anything at all. Here is what I get. I did install pylint by doing `pip install pylint`

```
$ pylint tunnel.py
  No config file found, using default configuration
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 910, in get_ast
return MANAGER.ast_from_file(filepath, modname, source=True)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 112, in ast_from_file
return AstroidBuilder(self).file_build(filepath, modname)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 134, in file_build
module = self._data_build(data, modname, path)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 177, in _data_build
module = rebuilder.visit_module(node, modname, node_file, package)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 148, in visit_module
newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 148, in <listcomp>
newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 161, in visit
return self._transform(visit_method(node, parent))
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 238, in visit_assign
newnode.value = self.visit(node.value, newnode)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 161, in visit
return self._transform(visit_method(node, parent))
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroid/rebuilder.py", line 331, in visit_callfunc
  if node.starargs is not None:
AttributeError: 'Call' object has no attribute 'starargs'
************* Module temp.test
F:  1, 0: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'Call' object has no attribute 'starargs' (astroid-error)
```

Comment: What does `pylint --version` say?

Comment: This is what I get


`$ pylint --version
   No config file found, using default configuration
   pylint 1.4.4, 
   astroid 1.3.8, common 1.2.2
  Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]`

Answer (score 0):

You're mentioning that you're using pylint 1.4.4, which is quite old and [won't work](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/643) with Python 3.5.

You should upgrade to the latest releases of pylint/astroid, e.g. by doing `pip install -U pylint`.